# python: ImportError: No module named pytz

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, sublimetext3

I'm working in a virtual environment. In terminal, I can do:

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
```

without issue. However, when I try to run the same code from a python file, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named pytz
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/<user>/Desktop/<project folder>/<python file>.py"]
[dir: /Users/<user>/Desktop/<project folder>]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Since I'm working in a virtual environment, why isn't it finding the pytz module? It seems like it's only looking in the usr/bin, /bin, etc folders. I even installed it like this outside my virtual environment:

```
pip install -U pytz
```

Not sure if it matters, but I don't have any shebangs in my python file.

Comment: If you run `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` from the command line it should tell you what path `python` will look in for modules.

Comment: @dg123 hmm... looks like it's looking in the right places: venv/lib/python35.zip, venv/lib/python3.5... and then after it looks at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5 where I installed it outside the venv. Anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Try adding `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + "venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages"))` somewhere in the top of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up moving my code from Sublime Text 3 over to PyCharm. This solved the issue.

Comment: I wonder if it's because Sublime Text 3 is still under development.